# Sending/Receiving SMS/MMS on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, text

Just got my first iPhone. Will not be using iMessages being I'm the only person in my social circle who has Apple products. Am I still able to send/receive SMS/MMS the "old" way on this phone? Also, due to the nature of my job, boss requires the phone stay off during working hours. Will I still be able to get any text messages sent to me once I'm able to turn my phone back on, even if it's a few days afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes and yes". SMS/MMS work the same way on iPhones as on any other phone (including any buffering your carrier does).